# what's the meaning of " a moment without an hour"?

Tags: meaning

I read a poem of Adam Zagajewski titled *Vita Contemplativa*, translated in English, and came across the verse

> *"a moment without an hour"*

Does it mean *"in a very short time"*?
Could anyone kindly help me with this?

Comment: Can you post the context of the verse? Context will help us understand what that phrasal excerpt means. Also, what research have you done, what have you found in your research, and why do you think it means *"in a very short time"*?

Comment: It would probably help to post the translation you found; but since it is a translation, it's just someone's idea of how to represent the original (Polish). [There are other translations](http://www.poetryinternationalweb.net/pi/site/poem/item/19221/auto/VITA-CONTEMPLATIVA) -- but ultimately, I think, the only person who can explain what is meant is the poet himself.

Comment: this is part of the poem,from another translation


"We seem to occupy a desert island.
Time moves deliberately, without haste. 
Helpless rapture, so this is the vita contemplativa.
An instant with no hour, as the poet said,
the poet killed in Lublin by a bomb.
But what if, in this or a different city,
the vita activa surged again, what would Artemis, 
fourth century B.C.E., do then? Hermes? Narcissus?"

Comment: I guessed the speaker talking about happiness/rapture would be gone quickly/instantly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a matter of poetic interpretation / Lit Crit. FWIW, I wonder if it might not be a reference to there not being any time "available, set aside" for the referent. In which case the prospects for "happiness" are even worse than for something whose *time has not yet come* (at least with *that* one, you might hope there *would* be a suitable time for it somewhen in the future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be complicated because it is related to a poem. I would submit, now that the poem is published, even the poet cannot objectively explain what the phrase means (somewhat similar to the whole 'gif' vs 'jif' thing). The poet could of course explain what he 'intended' and the poet's opinion would be valuable for that purpose. But what the phrase means is now open to interpretation for everyone.

The phrase seems to be a paradox (another popular example is `The Child is the father of the Man` by William Wordsworth). The poem is talking about "Contemplative Life" which does have some religious (Christian) connotations and refers to a life of quietude and prayer. In that phrase, the poet could be talking about a moment of reflection where the movement of time is not normal. But being a poem, it is not possible to say definitively what the meaning of that phrase is. And maybe that is the way it is meant to be.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am trying to find out what's the meaning itself literally and it seems not very clear to me